# How do I make two remote git branches point to the same commit?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

This is a slightly different version of the often asked "how do I get two git branches to point at the same commit".

I have **two remote** git branches called origin/A and origin/B.  Both are remote and both are in use by others.  Usually origin/B follows behind origin/A but can be easily fast-forwarded to catch up via:

```
git checkout -t origin/B
git merge origin/A
git push
```

Every once in awhile, we temporarily commit something unique to origin/B. Eventually the contents of origin/B get re-synchronized with origin/A.  However, after this occurs origin/B's HEAD is a different physical commit than origin/A (even though contents are diff-identical) and can no longer be fast-forwarded to origin/A.

What is the clean/right way to make origin/B point back to origin/A's HEAD at this point, so that future merges can be fast-forwaded?  I don't particularly care about branch history.

I know I can fix this on a local branch with rebase, or I can delete the remote branch and re-create it... but I think both these hurt other users of the remote branch.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why focus on managing remote branches, not local branches?

Comment: This problem is best handled by just merging or rebasing one branch on the other until they are up to date with each other.

Comment: We use the branches to control releases.  I think rebase would fix the issue with a local branch, but the docs imply that if I push this it would do something bad to other users that have the remote branches already checked out.  Unless I am misunderstanding the severity of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin --force origin/A:B
```

This will set `origin/B` to be the same commit as `origin/A`

Note that this is a **force** push and any branches based off of `origin/B` will contain commits that no longer exist in the `origin/A` branch.

Comment: Ah this looks like what I want.  One question: what will happen to other users when they 'git pull' after this?  Will it pull them cleanly from their position on the old branch to the new origin/A head?

Comment: Pulling from `origin/B` after this will be identical to pulling from `origin/A` (as they refer to the same commit).  Note that `git pull $branch` is basically just `git fetch && git merge $branch`

Comment: OK, so I tried this and it gave me this error.  I am up-to-date and 'git pull' doesn't help: git push origin --force origin/A:B

Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/B (you should pull first)
To host:/git/repo
 ! [remote rejected] origin/A -> B (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'host:/git/repo'

Comment: This implies that `denyNonFastForwards = true` is set in the remote repository's configuration (which prevents force pushes).  You'd need to change this on the remote repository (how that is done depends on what you're using to host, usually `ssh` and cd to the repository and use `git config ...`)

Comment: Ah, I see.  Although I also see why that would be a prudent protection to leave enabled.  Perhaps a server-side hook would be in order to enforce some policies here.  Bummer that there isn't some safer way to "jump-merge" back to an particular commit.  Oh well, thanks for all the new knowledge!  I'll go ponder all this.

Comment: Be very careful about using the force flag.  You are essentially turning off all gits safety measures.